# Linux Mint: Rotating external 4k screen causes extreme system sluggishness

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, intel-graphics, display-settings, amd-graphics

Note: I've included every system detail I can think of including at the bottom of the question.

I've been dealing with symptoms of systems sluggishness for a couple weeks on my laptop when docked using external screens. Moving windows is choppy, videos on either screen drop frames and stall, very bad screen tearing (this specifically might be a red herring, I've read this is a well known problem).

Setup while docked: Laptop screen disabled, one 4k monitor portrait, one 4k monitor landscape.

I installed and ran glmark2 3 times: Once on the laptop screen without the dock attached, once with the screens as described, once with the screen both in landscape mode. Full output below, but the scores were: ~2000, ~250, ~2000.

I'm reaching the end of my troubleshooting ability, and I haven't been able to find any good references to a problem matching these symptoms yet. It doesn't feel like a dock issue, as the glmark2 breadcrumb symptom isn't present when both screens are in landscape mode; but I'm open to suggestions to narrow this down to a possible dock issue.

Open to any requests for command output or suggestions to try to stabilize the configuration. I'm at a loss where to look next, I've been scouring video driver blog entries, distro bug listings, kernel bug listings, etc to no avail. I just want to be able to rotate my second screen without the system slowing to a crawl.

Quick note: You'll notice the glmark tests default to the Intel HD 630 display driver. Forcing the usage of the discrete Vega M by running with "env DRI_PRIME=1 glmark2" chip yields similar score results and discrepancies with a monitor in vertical orientation.

System Info:

```
Device: Dell 9575 2-in-1 laptop 
Dock: Dell TB-16 
Screens: Dell U2718Q, 3840x2160, 60Hz native

inxi -Fzx
System:
  Host: donatello Kernel: 4.18.20-041820-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  compiler: gcc v: 8.2.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.0.10 
  Distro: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: XPS 15 9575 v: N/A serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 0DV9HH v: A00 serial: <filter> UEFI: Dell v: 1.2.0 
  date: 10/10/2018 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 72.6 Wh condition: 72.6/75.0 Wh (97%) 
  model: BYD DELL TMFYT8B status: Full 
  Device-1: hid-f4:1b:a1:34:ad:0e-battery model: Trackpad 
  charge: N/A status: Discharging 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-8706G bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Kaby Lake rev: 9 L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 49536 
  Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/4100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 
  3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Device-2: AMD Polaris 22 [Radeon RX Vega M GL] driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
  bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: amdgpu,ati,modesetting 
  unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz, 3840x2160~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 18.2.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel CM238 HD Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel 
  v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
  Device-2: Realtek type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio bus ID: 3-1.5:4 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.18.20-041820-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: e000 
  bus ID: 02:00.0 
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Realtek type: USB driver: r8152 bus ID: 4-1.2:4 
  IF: enxc8f750c5b27b state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 89.55 GiB (18.8%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Toshiba model: KXG60ZNV512G NVMe 512GB 
  size: 476.94 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 44.77 GiB (9.6%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
  ID-2: swap-1 size: 2.00 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-0 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 60.5 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 51 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 313 Uptime: 13h 13m Memory: 15.39 GiB used: 3.63 GiB (23.6%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 7.3.0 clang: 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 
  Shell: bash v: 4.4.19 inxi: 3.0.27
```

.

```
Laptop screen only:
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     Intel Open Source Technology Center
    GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2) 
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 18.2.8
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false: FPS: 2669 FrameTime: 0.375 ms
[build] use-vbo=true: FPS: 2763 FrameTime: 0.362 ms
[texture] texture-filter=nearest: FPS: 2893 FrameTime: 0.346 ms
[texture] texture-filter=linear: FPS: 2837 FrameTime: 0.352 ms
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap: FPS: 2775 FrameTime: 0.360 ms
[shading] shading=gouraud: FPS: 2534 FrameTime: 0.395 ms
[shading] shading=blinn-phong-inf: FPS: 2551 FrameTime: 0.392 ms
[shading] shading=phong: FPS: 2348 FrameTime: 0.426 ms
[shading] shading=cel: FPS: 2261 FrameTime: 0.442 ms
[bump] bump-render=high-poly: FPS: 1742 FrameTime: 0.574 ms
[bump] bump-render=normals: FPS: 2947 FrameTime: 0.339 ms
[bump] bump-render=height: FPS: 2849 FrameTime: 0.351 ms
[effect2d] kernel=0,1,0;1,-4,1;0,1,0;: FPS: 1738 FrameTime: 0.575 ms
[effect2d] kernel=1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;: FPS: 1117 FrameTime: 0.895 ms
[pulsar] light=false:quads=5:texture=false: FPS: 2562 FrameTime: 0.390 ms
[desktop] blur-radius=5:effect=blur:passes=1:separable=true:windows=4: FPS: 1066 FrameTime: 0.938 ms
[desktop] effect=shadow:windows=4: FPS: 1609 FrameTime: 0.622 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 891 FrameTime: 1.122 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=subdata: FPS: 858 FrameTime: 1.166 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=true:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 980 FrameTime: 1.020 ms
[ideas] speed=duration: FPS: 2073 FrameTime: 0.482 ms
[jellyfish] <default>: FPS: 2044 FrameTime: 0.489 ms
[terrain] <default>: FPS: 249 FrameTime: 4.016 ms
[shadow] <default>: FPS: 2013 FrameTime: 0.497 ms
[refract] <default>: FPS: 591 FrameTime: 1.692 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 2748 FrameTime: 0.364 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 2606 FrameTime: 0.384 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 2777 FrameTime: 0.360 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=low:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 2784 FrameTime: 0.359 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=medium:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 2837 FrameTime: 0.352 ms
[loop] fragment-loop=false:fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 2839 FrameTime: 0.352 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=false:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 2794 FrameTime: 0.358 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=true:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 2682 FrameTime: 0.373 ms
=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 2152 
=======================================================
```

.

```
External Screens, both horizontal orientation
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     Intel Open Source Technology Center
    GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2) 
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 18.2.8
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false: FPS: 3246 FrameTime: 0.308 ms
[build] use-vbo=true: FPS: 3523 FrameTime: 0.284 ms
[texture] texture-filter=nearest: FPS: 3227 FrameTime: 0.310 ms
[texture] texture-filter=linear: FPS: 3244 FrameTime: 0.308 ms
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap: FPS: 3205 FrameTime: 0.312 ms
[shading] shading=gouraud: FPS: 2778 FrameTime: 0.360 ms
[shading] shading=blinn-phong-inf: FPS: 2846 FrameTime: 0.351 ms
[shading] shading=phong: FPS: 2566 FrameTime: 0.390 ms
[shading] shading=cel: FPS: 2585 FrameTime: 0.387 ms
[bump] bump-render=high-poly: FPS: 1874 FrameTime: 0.534 ms
[bump] bump-render=normals: FPS: 3372 FrameTime: 0.297 ms
[bump] bump-render=height: FPS: 3194 FrameTime: 0.313 ms
[effect2d] kernel=0,1,0;1,-4,1;0,1,0;: FPS: 1829 FrameTime: 0.547 ms
[effect2d] kernel=1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;: FPS: 1128 FrameTime: 0.887 ms
[pulsar] light=false:quads=5:texture=false: FPS: 2754 FrameTime: 0.363 ms
[desktop] blur-radius=5:effect=blur:passes=1:separable=true:windows=4: FPS: 1082 FrameTime: 0.924 ms
[desktop] effect=shadow:windows=4: FPS: 1781 FrameTime: 0.561 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 1007 FrameTime: 0.993 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=subdata: FPS: 482 FrameTime: 2.075 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=true:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 642 FrameTime: 1.558 ms
[ideas] speed=duration: FPS: 664 FrameTime: 1.506 ms
[jellyfish] <default>: FPS: 1929 FrameTime: 0.518 ms
[terrain] <default>: FPS: 226 FrameTime: 4.425 ms
[shadow] <default>: FPS: 1759 FrameTime: 0.569 ms
[refract] <default>: FPS: 371 FrameTime: 2.695 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 2127 FrameTime: 0.470 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 2527 FrameTime: 0.396 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 2727 FrameTime: 0.367 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=low:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 2402 FrameTime: 0.416 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=medium:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 2642 FrameTime: 0.379 ms
[loop] fragment-loop=false:fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 2675 FrameTime: 0.374 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=false:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 2280 FrameTime: 0.439 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=true:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 1708 FrameTime: 0.585 ms
=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 2133 
=======================================================
```

.

```
External Screens, one horizontal, one vertical orientation
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     Intel Open Source Technology Center
    GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2) 
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 18.2.8
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false: FPS: 248 FrameTime: 4.032 ms
[build] use-vbo=true: FPS: 351 FrameTime: 2.849 ms
[texture] texture-filter=nearest: FPS: 315 FrameTime: 3.175 ms
[texture] texture-filter=linear: FPS: 332 FrameTime: 3.012 ms
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap: FPS: 333 FrameTime: 3.003 ms
[shading] shading=gouraud: FPS: 293 FrameTime: 3.413 ms
[shading] shading=blinn-phong-inf: FPS: 311 FrameTime: 3.215 ms
[shading] shading=phong: FPS: 286 FrameTime: 3.497 ms
[shading] shading=cel: FPS: 266 FrameTime: 3.759 ms
[bump] bump-render=high-poly: FPS: 229 FrameTime: 4.367 ms
[bump] bump-render=normals: FPS: 344 FrameTime: 2.907 ms
[bump] bump-render=height: FPS: 319 FrameTime: 3.135 ms
[effect2d] kernel=0,1,0;1,-4,1;0,1,0;: FPS: 234 FrameTime: 4.274 ms
[effect2d] kernel=1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;: FPS: 139 FrameTime: 7.194 ms
[pulsar] light=false:quads=5:texture=false: FPS: 287 FrameTime: 3.484 ms
[desktop] blur-radius=5:effect=blur:passes=1:separable=true:windows=4: FPS: 134 FrameTime: 7.463 ms
[desktop] effect=shadow:windows=4: FPS: 202 FrameTime: 4.950 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 57 FrameTime: 17.544 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=subdata: FPS: 102 FrameTime: 9.804 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=true:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 60 FrameTime: 16.667 ms
[ideas] speed=duration: FPS: 179 FrameTime: 5.587 ms
[jellyfish] <default>: FPS: 227 FrameTime: 4.405 ms
[terrain] <default>: FPS: 67 FrameTime: 14.925 ms
[shadow] <default>: FPS: 224 FrameTime: 4.464 ms
[refract] <default>: FPS: 79 FrameTime: 12.658 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 271 FrameTime: 3.690 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 263 FrameTime: 3.802 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 271 FrameTime: 3.690 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=low:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 275 FrameTime: 3.636 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=medium:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 265 FrameTime: 3.774 ms
[loop] fragment-loop=false:fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 277 FrameTime: 3.610 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=false:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 271 FrameTime: 3.690 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=true:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 273 FrameTime: 3.663 ms
=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 235 
=======================================================
```

Comment: Have you uninstalled and reinstalled the graphics drivers? Corruption in a graphics driver could be problematic, and I'd check there first.